# Using a datatype with another and instantiate it

Tags: haskell

I'm stumpled with a problem using datatypes... I've been following [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) alongside my IT grad but regarding datatypes I'm really messed up on the use of them, and how you can use one with another
Basically:

```
class Prior a where
priority :: a -> Int


--Someway to represent a person basic attributes
--If possible this way: 
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , age :: Int 
                     , invalid :: Bool
                     } 

 --Then to instantiate Prior and Person
instance Prioritizavel Pessoa where
priority a = ...  
--Assuming a is person, something like if invalid then 0 else 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Err, you mixed languages (Pessoa vs Person) in your code. Also, do you have a concrete question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the purpose of the typeclass here. I'm guessing there are supposed to be other instances.
The following works fine:

```
class Prior a where
    priority :: a -> Int

data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , age :: Int 
                     , invalid :: Bool
                     } 

instance Prior Person where
    priority (Person _ _ i) = fromEnum $ not i  -- if invalid then 0 else 1
```

so does

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , age :: Int 
                     , invalid :: Bool
                     } 

priority :: Person -> Int
priority (Person _ _ i) = fromEnum $ not i
```

as a side note, you aren't 'instantiating' the class. Creating an instance doesn't create a new object or a new type. *In fact, information about classes is not available at runtime*. If you have

```
class C a where c :: a -> Int

instance C Bool where c = ...
instance C Int  where c = ...
```

This creates a dictionary containing the functions `c_bool` and `c_int` and the runtime choses one based on the context (ie calling `c` on a Bool chooses `c_bool`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`class` defines a type class, not a concrete data type. `Person` is a concrete data type. A type class is a collection of concrete data types, all of which "provide" common operation(s) - in this case, `priority`.

It sounds like you want to define a person's priority as being lower if the data is "invalid" in some sense, or higher if it is valid. But you don't actually need a type class for that - you just need a function, `priority`. A type class would be used if you had multiple data types, all supporting a priority operation.